# How do I create more than one file in specific folder without repeating the path name?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

How can I create more than one file within a folder with the `touch` command?  More specifically, lets say, I want to create three new files - `local.js`, `facebook.js` and `twitter.js` in a folder that has path `config/strategies/`.  This is what I am currently doing:

`touch config/strategies/local.js config/strategies/facebook.js config/strategies/twitter.js`.

What I want to know is if there is a shorter way to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bash's brace expansion:

```
$ touch config/strategies/{local,facebook,twitter}.js
$ ls config/strategies/
facebook.js  local.js  twitter.js
```

#### More Information

Brace expansion comes in two forms.  The first uses commas between items in the list:

```
$ echo 1{b,c}2
1b2 1c2
```

The second uses `..` and causes a sequence of words to be created:

```
$ echo 1{a..f}2
1a2 1b2 1c2 1d2 1e2 1f2
```

With a sequence, it is also possible to specify an increment:

```
$ echo 1{a..f..2}2
1a2 1c2 1e2
```

With 2 specified as the increment, then every other letter between `a` and `f` is generated by the expansion